# What happens to InProc sessions during App Service maintenance?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been reading about what happens during App Service maintenance here (https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/01/18/Demystifying-the-magic-behind-App-Service-OS-updates.html) and it states:

> When the update reaches a specific region, we update available
> instances without apps on them, then move the apps to the updated
> instances, then update the offloaded instances.

Will any InProc sessions simply get lost if this happens? Or is there something more clever happening to mirror sessions in this case?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `InProc sessions` will get lost if in maintenance.

You can refer to [this article](https://www.alachisoft.com/blogs/storing-asp-net-session-state-in-a-microsoft-azure-distributed-cache/) -> the `InProc Option` section for more details.